# How to view serial COM ports but not through Device Manager

Tags: command-line, serial-port, com-port

How would I go about viewing a list of COM ports in use without the use of [Device Manager](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_Manager)?

I don't want to install any software either. Is there a possible way to do this through the command line?

Comment: Please better define "In Use". installed as a device? Has a device attached to it? Is actively transferring data?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 sorry, in use would be having a device attached to it. I have a ttl uart cable plugged into a USB.

Comment: I suppose you can do this through a powershell script.  Why can't you use device manager?  Your unwillingness to use something like Putty is odd.

Comment: @Ramhound Using a University PC which has the device manager locked down to stop people like me fiddling. I can see that the device is COM3 on my laptop. I want to use Putty but I don't know which COM port to use.

Comment: @Marmstrong In the command prompt use `mode`. Used without parameters, `mode` displays all the controllable attributes of the `CON` (console) and the available `COM` devices (and `LPT` as well)

Answer (score 94, accepted):

In the command prompt use

`mode`

Used without parameters, `mode` displays all the controllable attributes of the `CON` (console) and the available `COM` devices (and `LPT` as well).

Accepts `/?` switch for basic help:

`mode /?`

Comment: Using `mode` most of the time I don't see the devices that are not connected, as mentioned in @G-M 's answer.

Comment: `mode` is for configuring system devices. This does work... until I connect something like Putty to the COM port. Which I guess makes sense, it the port is not configurable while in use. A better "query only" method is in @lithiumhead's answer.

Answer (score 29):

I know the question has been answered, but this is another method.

In command prompt, use:
`chgport`
in windows Vista and up. Lists your ports and which device they are.

Comment: Windows 7 "'chgport' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: works for me on Win 7

Comment: chgport /QUERY works for me in Win7 pro. It lists the \Device\name for the currently select com port, not a full list. More interesting, chgport /? shows: (formatting fails)
CHANGE PORT [portx=porty | /D portx | /QUERY]
 portx=porty  Map port x to port y.
 /D portx    Delete mapping for port x.
 /QUERY      Display current mapping ports.
And chgport COM4=COM5 allows type COM4: to work!

Comment: `chgport` [Applies To: Windows Server (Semi-Annual Channel), Windows Server 2016, Windows Server 2012 R2, Windows Server 2012](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chgport).

Comment: chgport also works in Windows 10

Comment: Just tested OK as well in Windows 10. Can't verify outside of enterprise systems though.

Comment: Did not work for me. I get `Unable to get list of COM ports, error code = 0x5.
No serial ports were found.` Windows 10 Enterprise, 20H2

Comment: Just my two-cents as this does not appear to be a universal solution for Windows, adding another datapoint as it also doesn't work on Win 11 (Home 22621.1265). Answer should include exactly what's required to be able to use this program, as it works for some and not others I suspect a Home vs Pro version of Windows?

Answer (score 19):

In the command prompt use:

```
C:\>wmic path Win32_SerialPort
```

In PowerShell, **run as administrator**:

```
PS> Get-WMIObject Win32_SerialPort | Select-Object Name,DeviceID,Description
```

Or, for raw data:

```
PS> Get-WMIObject Win32_SerialPort
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The command prompt returned `No Instance(s) Available.`

Comment: If there are no Com port devices detect then the command results "No Instance(s) Available". Check your "Device Manager" and ensure your machine detected the Com ports in "Device Manager"

Comment: OP said "Using a University PC which has the device manager locked down"

Comment: @vembutech - Looks like you will need to get IT involved in that case.

Comment: @vembutech I have checked the device on my own laptop and it appears as COM3 in device manager but the command prompt still shows the same result.

Comment: Make sure you run the PS command as administrator.

Answer (score 14):

You can also run the following from cmd.exe prompt

```
reg query HKLM\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM
```

And here is an open source utility to do the same and more:
https://todbot.com/blog/2012/03/02/listcomports-windows-command-line-tool-for-usb-to-serial/

Comment: Thanks! This actually worked.

Answer (score 8):

Using `mode` most of the time I don't see the devices that are not connected.

I prefer to use this solution with Python:

```
python -c "import serial.tools.list_ports as ls; print([p.device for p in ls.comports()])"
```

So I can see anything plugged in even if the connection is closed.

*serial.tools.list_ports* is from package **pyserial**.

Comment: idk when this worked, but now the `__repr__` of the objects has changed and I get `[<serial.tools.list_ports_common.ListPortInfo object at 0x00000000036ECCC8>, <serial.tools.list_ports_common.ListPortInfo object at 0x00000000036ECD88>]`

Comment: looks like you need the `description` or `device` properties now: `python -c "import serial.tools.list_ports as ls;print [p.device for p in ls.comports()]"`

Answer (score 7):

wmic https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/wmic is a 
windows command line utility to get system information.

If your serial port is virtual created by some driver through USB connection, use this example to get details about these serial ports.

```
wmic path CIM_LogicalDevice where "Description like 'USB Serial%'" get /value
```

Comment: a bit of further information would be helpfull

Comment: that produces lots of information. `get Name` instead of `get /value` might help. Unfortunately, it won't simply list ports, but strings such as "USB Serial Port (COM17)". There are also multiple entries mentioning simply "USB Serial Converter" on my setup.

Answer (score 1):

The snippet below lists serial ports into the $PORTS variable

```
# BASH MSYS2
# This function will get a list of ports automatically
PORTS=`/c/Windows/System32/mode.com | grep Status.*COM | awk '{ print $4 }' | sed s/://`

# To the list (use) the ports, see the code below:

echo -n "Programming (echoing) ports: "
for aa in $PORTS; do
    echo -n $aa
done
echo ""
```

Comment: What I like about this answer is that I can use it within a bash script.