# How to view descriptive name on windows command prompt

Tags: windows, command-line, serial-port, com-port

Expand from the question [about viewing serial ports not through device manager](https://superuser.com/questions/835848/how-to-view-serial-com-ports-but-not-through-device-manager): How can you see the descriptive names?

The port is on a USB-serial adapter. The `teraterm` application can show it as `COM14: USB-SERIAL CH340 (COM14)`. I'd like to see the `USB-SERIAL` and the `CH340` part.

Using the commands from the linked answers:

- `mode` : It does not show the `USB-SERIAL` or `CH340` part.
- `wmic path Win32_SerialPort` : The result screen is very wide and not containing the information being asked for.
- `PS> Get-WMIObject Win32_SerialPort` : It shows only the lower-numbered ports, `COM1` and `COM3`. No `COM14` and `COM15` those are connected through USB-adapter.
- `chgport` : The result does not contain the information being asked for.

Comment: Are you asking about serial/COM ports or USB ports?

Comment: I'm asking about the serial/COM ports. When the ports are over the USB ports, as the teraterm shows in its GUI, the serial/COM port can be shown with the 'USB-SERIAL' and other descriptions that is associated to the port. When the serial/COM ports are not over USB there are other descriptive information too. I'm looking for a way to show those extra information.