# difference between COM port DeviceManager data and mode command in Windows

Tags: windows, command-line, com

Why Windows mode command (`mode COMX`) is showing different data then same COMX has in Windows "DeviceManager", under Ports/Properties. Are these supposed to be in sync? See [COM port via command line](https://superuser.com/questions/835848/how-to-view-serial-com-ports-but-not-through-device-manager) .

The different data comes for Baud rate, Data parity, Data bits ...
For example : Baud rate (DM - 115200, MODE - 1200), Parity (DM-7, MODE - 8).

Comment: Please augment your question to show the two conflicting sets of data. We can't guess what differences you're seeing.

Answer (score 2):

The Windows Command Prompt is *just* an application, it is not an interface to the system configuration options, though you may be able to set or configure the system *via* Command Prompt commands.

What `mode COMx` will do is configure the settings for applications launched via *that particular instance* of the Command Prompt. If you do an `echo "hello" >COMx` after using the `mode` command then it will use the settings you configure.

Every program "sees" a consistent and "clean" configuration of the COM port based on the defaults set in Device Manager. You can subsequently configure the COM port in an application but it does not affect the defaults.