# List all the serial ports (available and busy) on any of windows terminals

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, cmd.exe, serial-port

The cmd's `mode` command shows all the available (to be opened) serial ports, omitting the ones which are occupied by other programs. The PowerShell's command:

```
[System.IO.Ports.SerialPort]::getportnames()
```

shows all the existing ports even if they have been opened by other software. However, it doesn't show the ports which have been opened internally by PS itself. For example, if I define a new port object by:

```
$port= new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM3,9600,None,8,one
```

the `mode` command does not list 'COM3', indicating that the port is actually open in another program (i.e., PS). But the first PS command above still shows it as available. Somehow PS already opens the port when the object is defined but still lists them as available! Now if I open the port in PS:

```
$port.Open()
```

PS doesn't list it anymore.

What I want is to have a `cmd` or PS command to list all the serial ports regardless of they are being opened in a program or not.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/835848/how-to-view-serial-com-ports-but-not-through-device-manager - 8

In the command prompt use:

C:\>wmic path Win32_SerialPort
OR

In PowerShell:

PS> Get-WMIObject Win32_SerialPort
OR

PS> Get-WMIObject Win32_SerialPort | Select-Object Name,DeviceID,Description
Hope this helps.

Comment: @spikey_richie `cmd`'s `wmic` and `chgport` or PS's `Get-WMIObject` are the options. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

1. Click on a start menu
2. Go to "run"
3. in the field type CMD
4. execute this commands in this order:
    a) C:>powershell
    b) PS> Get-WMIObject Win32_SerialPort

If you are x64 so type win64.

It should work i guess.

Comment: or try this -> C:\>wmic path Win32_SerialPort

Comment: the first comment on the original post points towards a another post with a lot of nice solutions including the ones you just mentioned. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. Have a nice time

Answer (score 0):

To list all serial ports on a Windows system, whether they're available or busy, one can use this PowerShell script. This script enhances the functionality mentioned from both CMD and PowerShell, providing a comprehensive view of the serial port status on the system. Here's a summary of how the script works and what it does:

#### Script Overview

The script utilizes the `.NET` class `[System.IO.Ports.SerialPort]::getportnames()` to retrieve all serial port names on the system. It then attempts to open each serial port to determine its status. If a port can be successfully opened, it's considered "available." If the script encounters an error while trying to open a port (indicating the port is in use or otherwise unavailable), it marks the port as "busy."

#### How It Works

1. **Retrieve Serial Ports**: The script starts by getting a list of all serial port names available on the system.
2. **Check Port Status**: For each port, the script attempts to initialize and open the port. If this process succeeds, the script immediately closes the port (to avoid interfering with subsequent operations) and marks the port as available. If the script cannot open a port (due to it being in use or any other error), it catches the exception and marks the port as busy.
3. **Report Results**: Finally, the script generates a custom PowerShell object for each port, indicating the port name and its status (available or busy). These objects are collected into an array and outputted as a table, providing a clear and concise overview of the status of all serial ports on the system.

#### The Script

```
# Initialize an array to hold the port status objects
$portStatuses = @()

# Get all serial port names
$ports = [System.IO.Ports.SerialPort]::getportnames()

foreach ($port in $ports) {
    try {
        # Try to initialize the port
        $testPort = new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort $port,9600,None,8,one
        $testPort.Open() # Try to open the port
        $testPort.Close() # Close the port if it was successfully opened
        
        # Create a custom object with port details and status
        $portStatus = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            PortName = $port
            Status = 'Available'
        }
    }
    catch {
        # If an exception is caught, the port is busy
        $portStatus = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            PortName = $port
            Status = 'Busy'
        }
    }
    # Add the custom object to the array
    $portStatuses += $portStatus
}

# Output the array as a table
$portStatuses | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

This solution provides a more detailed and dynamic approach than simply listing ports using CMD's `mode` command or PowerShell's `[System.IO.Ports.SerialPort]::getportnames()` alone. It actively checks each port's status, offering a clearer picture of which ports are currently in use and which are available for new connections.