# How to force closing / freeing the serial ports opened by other programs in cmd or Powershell

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, cmd.exe, serial-port

Following [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/1412117/list-all-the-serial-ports-available-and-busy-on-any-of-windows-terminals), I can use `cmd`'s `mode` command to see the available / free ports. I can also use the PowerShell (PS) 's oneliner:

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_SerialPort | Select-Object DeviceID
```

to see all the existing ports. The difference indicates the Open / busy ports.

Now I want to interrupt (force close) the ports which are open in any way, including the ones opened outside `cmd`/PS. Please consider

1. The port is not necessarily opened inside PS. otherwise I could use `$<PortName>.Close()` to do this.
2. It has to be a `cmd` or PS command not a GUI solution like editing the registry or restating the operating system.
3. I don't want to delete / destroy the port. I just want to be sure they are free (ready to be opened)
4. It should be preferably a one-liner. Something I can run in just one line. using piping is ok.

**P.S.** I have also posted the question [here on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/ayhfwh/how_to_force_closing_freeing_the_serial_ports/)

Comment: Did you try `Reset` method of the `CIM_LogicalDevice` class?

Comment: @JosefZ No I haven't. Would you please elaborate? I'm trying [this solution](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/ayhfwh/how_to_force_closing_freeing_the_serial_ports/ei0sr2c) for the moment.

Answer (score 1):

[DevCon Restart: Stops and restarts the specified devices. Valid only on the local computer.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/devcon-restart)

> Example 38: Restart a device
>
> The following command uses the DevCon Restart operation to restart the
>   loopback adapter on the local computer. The command limits the search
>   to the Net setup class and, within that class, specifies the device
>   instance ID of the loopback adapter, ROOT*MSLOOP\0000. The at
>   character (@) identifies the string as an device instance ID. The
>   single quote character ('), which requests a literal search, prevents
>   DevCon from interpreting the asterisk in the ID as a wildcard
>   character.

```
devcon restart =net @'ROOT\*MSLOOP\0000
```

Or otherwise, drilling into what is available and what you can take action on.

> Understanding - Writing and Reading info from Serial Ports
>
> http://www.powertheshell.com/reference/wmireference/root/cimv2/Win32_SerialPort
>   http://www.powertheshell.com/reference/wmireference/root/cimv2/Win32_SerialPort/Reset
>   https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/writing-and-reading-info-from-serial-ports

```
(Get-WMIObject Win32_SerialPort).DeviceID

# COM3

Get-CimClass -ClassName Win32_SerialPort | Format-List -Force

...
CimClassMethods     : {SetPowerState, Reset}
...
```

> Methods
>
> The Win32_SerialPort class has these methods.
>
> Method Description
>
> Reset Not implemented. To implement this method,
>   see the Reset method in CIM_SerialController.
>
> SetPowerState Not
>   implemented. To implement this method, 
>   see the SetPowerState method in CIM_SerialController.
>
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/CIMWin32Prov/win32-serialport

```
Get-CimClass -ClassName CIM_LogicalDevice | Format-List -Force

Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_LogicalDevice | 
Where-Object -Property DeviceID -EQ $((Get-WMIObject Win32_SerialPort).DeviceID) | 
Select-Object -Property '*' | Get-Member

Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_LogicalDevice | 
Where-Object -Property DeviceID -EQ $((Get-WMIObject Win32_SerialPort).DeviceID) | 
Select-Object -Property TimeOfLastReset


# Writing to a Serial Port using .Net namespace accelerator

[System.IO.Ports.SerialPort]::getportnames()
COM3
$port = New-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM3,9600,None,8,one
$port.open()
$port.WriteLine(“Hello world”)
$port.Close()


# Reading from a Serial Port using .Net namespace accelerator
$port = New-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM3,9600,None,8,one
$port.Open()
$port.ReadLine()
```

Answer (score 1):

\Device\Serial*n* , where *n* starts at 0, are the internal device names of the serial ports, and it's handles to these that you need to close.

It's not going to be one line, but ...

Download the "handle" utility from the SysInternals tools.

From an elevated command prompt, run `handle device\serial >temp.txt`

The file will contain a bunch of lines of the form:

`image.exe       pid: 24944  type: File            4C: \Device\Serialn`

For each such line, run (as admin): `handle -p <pid> -c <handleValue> -y`

The last hex value on each line of `handle` output  (4C in the example shown) is the handle value you want. So for example, you would close that handle via

`handle -p 24944 -c 4c -y`